# Prime and Painting Bare Radiator Covers - Sandblasted Bare Metal

Tags: painting, metal, repainting

What are some reasonable primer and paint for bare metal radiator covers? I had them sandblasted so they are bare metal.

In the past I once painted a cast iron radiator with Rust-Oleum Clean Metal Primer, and then went over with Hammered Rust-Oleum and it seemed to hold up well.

Is the Rust-Oleum Clean Metal Primer ideal in this case? Nearly all of the Rust-Oleum products state they are suitable for surfaces up to 200F, so radiators running at about 165F-170F should not be an issue.

Curious if anyone else has painted radiator covers, and radiators, and what you've had success with.